# Passing javascript variable to iframe src

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Can someone help me if correcting this code. I couldnt figure out where i went wrong. The javascript variable is not replacing the src.

P.S. This should run as a **Google Chrome extensions**.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function convert()
            {   
            var url4="test"
            document.getElementById("link").src=url4;
            } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="convert()">
        <iframe src="wwwx" id="link" width="100%" height="300">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats not working? The src attribute should be a url.

Comment: This seems to actually work: http://jsfiddle.net/XE7Wu/1/

Comment: It seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/VkbHw/.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko, "test" is a valid relative path

Comment: If it was run as a Google Chrome extension, you should have specified so in the tags, please do it next time (I did it for you this time)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Extension: Passing javascript variable to iframe src](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127297/google-chrome-extension-passing-javascript-variable-to-iframe-src)

Answer (score -1):

Because the JavaScript is being run before the `<iframe>` is in the DOM, it will never be able to access it.

Try moving your JS to just after the iframe but before the `</body>` tag:

```
<html> 
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="wwwx" id="link" width="100%" height="300">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
   <script>
     function convert() {   
       var url4 = "test";
       document.getElementById("link").src=url4;
     }

     convert(); 
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, the function is called on load.

Comment: That's not correct. The function is executed at `onload`, which is after everything has been loaded, including the DOM.

Comment: body onload should not be used. Also, the code I posted works. Please don't vote down without a clear understanding of the language.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but 'JavaScript is being run before the <iframe> is in the DOM' is just not correct.

Comment: Thanx. I fixed that, so it works fine when run as a normal web page but doesnt work in chrome extension

Comment: <html> 
<head> 
</head>
<body >
<iframe src="www" id="link" width="400" height="300">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
<script>
var url1="xxx";
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
var url1= tab.url;
});
document.getElementById("link").src=url1;
</script>
</body>
</html>