# Google Chrome Extension: Passing javascript variable to iframe src

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have added "tabs" in permissions but this code doesnt work . The iframe works when the url is passed directly but not from the script.

```
    <html> 
    <head> 
    </head>
    <body >
    <iframe src="www" id="link" width="400" height="300">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
    <script>
    var url1="xxx";
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    var url1= tab.url;
    });
    document.getElementById("link").src=url1;
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 'Your browser does not support iframes.' is rubbish if it is an extension for Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand the question.

You would need to add to your content script manifest the permission to access that page that has the iframe. Once you do, you use [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) and its [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to pass data to that iframe.

In the example above, you would need to inject a content script, so in your manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://www.my.injected.url/*"],
    "js": ["injected_script_that_has_the_iframe.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": true
}]
```

Then in that content script, you can do normal JavaScript to set the URL:

```
document.getElementById("link").src= someURL;
```

Now, where is that URL coming from? Is it coming from your extension? If so, use Message Passing to request that.

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "GetURL"}, function(response) {
  document.getElementById("link").src= response.url;
});
```

And within your background page, you listen for requests coming from your background page:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "GetURL")
      sendResponse({url: "http://rim.com"});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

To recap, your content script asks your extension (background page), what the URL is, and once it gets a response, it updates the iframe.

Comment: Actually this is what I want: i)Detect the URL of the current tab (lets say www.site1.com/xyz) ii)Extract the 'xyz' part from the url iii)Add that part to another url ( and make it something like www.site2.com/xyz) iii) open the new url in the iframe. I thought of starting by opening the same url in the iframe and add more operations if it works out , but couldnt get past this stage yet

Comment: You could detect the URL by doing `window.location`. Then embed the iframe inside with the new URL. That is how I would have done it.